# SQL code to generate XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am new to writing XML in SQL and desperately need some help to write the SQL for the following xml output.  I am sure one of you guys will find it really easy!  any help greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PaymentList>
<Payment>
<PaymentTypeField>BACS_Payment</PaymentTypeField>
<DebitSortCodeField>300009</DebitSortCodeField>
<DebitAccountNumberField>01163208</DebitAccountNumberField>
<PaymentCurrencyField>GBP</PaymentCurrencyField>
<ValueDateField>17-JUN-2016</ValueDateField>
<DebitAccountNameField>TEST LTD</DebitAccountNameField>
<BeneficiaryList>
<BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="RT & BS LANE"Amount="5443.64" SortCode="202400" AccountNumber="30305146"/>
<BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="CANNON HYGIENE LTD" Amount="197.14" SortCode="400250" AccountNumber="81001884"/>
<BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="COMPLETE OFFICE SO" Amount="102.00" SortCode="406135" AccountNumber="03006513”/>
</BeneficiaryList>
</Payment>
</PaymentList>
```

Thanks
Paul..

Comment: Starting from what? What is the data source?

Comment: Which RDBMS (vendor and version?)

Comment: Sorry all! This is on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 if that helps?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact, that your XML has some flaws (the date format and the `&` as not escaped character in "RT & BS LANE" and besides the fact that you did not show your data's sources, this would be a query returning exactly your example:

```
SELECT 'BACS_Payment' AS PaymentTypeField
      ,30009 AS DebitSortCodeField
      ,'01163208' AS DebitAccountNumberField
      ,'GBP' AS PaymentCurrencyField
      ,'2016-06-17' AS ValueDateField --ATTENTION: Avoid culture specific formats!!!
      ,'TEST LTD' AS DebitAccountNameField
      ,(
        SELECT *
        FROM
        (
         SELECT 
                'BACS170616' AS [@PaymentReferenceNumber]
               ,'RT & BS LANE' AS [@Name]
               ,5443.64 AS [@Amount]
               ,'202400' AS [@SortCode]
               ,'30305146' AS [@AccountNumber]

         UNION ALL SELECT 'BACS170616','CANNON HYGIENE LTD',197.14,'400250','81001884'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'BACS170616','COMPLETE OFFICE SO',102.00,'406135','03006513'

        ) AS subselect
        FOR XML PATH('BeneficiaryItem'),ROOT('BeneficiaryList'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('Paymnent'),ROOT('PaymentList');
```

#### Attention

The `UNION ALL` in the middle is just a *mock up* for a 1:n related data table which - probably - is the source for your list of `BeneficiaryItem`s. You place there a simple select with a proper `WHERE` clause to read the data related to the outer query. The rest should be quite close to your needs...

This is the result

```
<PaymentList>
  <Paymnent>
    <PaymentTypeField>BACS_Payment</PaymentTypeField>
    <DebitSortCodeField>30009</DebitSortCodeField>
    <DebitAccountNumberField>01163208</DebitAccountNumberField>
    <PaymentCurrencyField>GBP</PaymentCurrencyField>
    <ValueDateField>2016-06-17</ValueDateField>
    <DebitAccountNameField>TEST LTD</DebitAccountNameField>
    <BeneficiaryList>
      <BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="RT &amp; BS LANE" Amount="5443.64" SortCode="202400" AccountNumber="30305146" />
      <BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="CANNON HYGIENE LTD" Amount="197.14" SortCode="400250" AccountNumber="81001884" />
      <BeneficiaryItem PaymentReferenceNumber="BACS170616" Name="COMPLETE OFFICE SO" Amount="102.00" SortCode="406135" AccountNumber="03006513" />
    </BeneficiaryList>
  </Paymnent>
</PaymentList>
```

Comment: That's brilliant it shows exactly how I want!  Just another silly question, when I run the code in sql and click the results it displays as above, if I try to open the xml in the web I get different formatting?  what should the user open the xml up in to see the same results?

Comment: This depends on your needs...  You might use a query like this `SELECT CAST((SELECT CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` to get the XML *as is* but you will miss the indents... Creating XML is one thing, display is a completely different one. So, if this issue is solved, please tick the acceptance check and start a new question. As a positive side effect a new question will draw much more attention!

Comment: For display purposes on a web page I'd look for an `XSLT` approach actually... With XSLT you can create indented output.

Comment: @PaulTippet It is very kind of you to state *That's brilliant* but it would be even kinder to tick the acceptance check. This is good to close the question as solved and it will pay some reputation points to your and to mine account. Accepting and Voting are the ways to say *Thank you* on SO, THX